# Editing Tizen manifest file

Tags: xamarin, dependencies, manifest, tizen

I am currently trying to utilize the following NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media

In the readme included I am instructed to edit the Tizen-manifest.xml, however despite looking through my project solution, my files, tinkering with visual studio, and hours of googling I cannot seem to find this file. Noob here, what am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: What do you do to use this package so that you need to edit the `Tizen-manifest.xml`? Do you use the `Tizen`?

Comment: Yes I was planning on using a third party nuget package to access media from users and allow them to upload it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tizen-manifest.xml is configuration file for Tizen Application.
- C version: Need to use Tizen Studio
- C# version: Need to use Visual Studio + Tizen Plugin + Tizen Base SDK